# Update for adding Telegram Bot to channel

Tags: api, bots, telegram

When I add my bot to a group or supergroup, I get the update in the right format

```
{"update_id":366723634,
"message":{"message_id":33,"from":{"id":***,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"name","username":"name","language_code":"en-US"},"chat":{"id":***,"title":"Bot Test","type":"supergroup"},"date":1523443381,"new_chat_participant":{"id":***,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"Bot Name","username":"username"},"new_chat_member":{"id":***,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"Bot Name","username":"username"},"new_chat_members":[{"id":***,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"Name","username":"username"}]}}
```

However when the bot is added to a channel, no update is receive.  I have searched the entire API manual and can't find anything related to this.

1. Is this normal?
2. If this is normal, how then do I know when my bot is added to a channel?

I use webhook. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, this is "normal", no `message` update for channel posts.
2. Your [update](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) should contains `channel_post` instead of `message`

> channel_post: New incoming channel post of any kind — text, photo, sticker, etc.

Comment: Which means when I add a bot to a channel, I can't receive the update. How then am I to know when my bot is added to a channel? Because I didn't receive any update at all not "message" not "channel_post"